# Outlook 2007 and Sharepoint Services Issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, sharepoint, exchange-2003, outlook-2007, sharepoint-services

We have a Windows Sharepoint Services (WSS 3.0) Project Management site on one of our Windows 2003 servers.

We are trying to give our users access to forms showing them the status of their requests and a form to allow them to add projects through Outlook 2007 which runs on Exchange 2003.

We found a post on how to add a new folder item in Outlook and set the Home Page as the sharepoint URL for application pages (web part pages created through WSS).

This works very well, except where you try and use a Person Lookup button or edit the properties of a document in a document list. (i.e http://myserver.local/ProjectSite/Project1.aspx)

I have noticed that the address box in Outlook shows "Outlook:ITInformation\My Live Projects".

If you click on one of the Sharepoint Quick Menu or Top Menu items that appear Outlook Window, the address box changes to http:// address of the page on the Sharepoint and buttons and menus work.

Also if I create a folder linking to the main page site (http://myserver.local/ProjectSite/) and click on the links everything works fine.

I am trying to create a focused version for our users rather than them have to work their way through the whole site to get to the information relevant to them.

I have searched the web for information on this, but I have now reached a brick wall.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you thought about using alerts for all of the modified items of a document library? If a status gets updated, all users can potentially get alerts.

Comment: Hi Mike, We have thought of alerts but that is not the issue we are facing. We want users to have one application to do all. Having to open IE will result in the Sharepoint site being ignored. I'm beginning to think that Sharepoint is not the solution for knowledge sharing withing Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks Like there is no solutions so am closing the question off